# What Jabber/XMPP libraries are available for PyS60 (Python for Symbian S60) interpreter?

Tags: python, symbian, xmpp, pys60

I'm interested in developing a XMPP client on the mobile S60 Symbian platform using the Python interpreter PyS60. I've done a search on Google for possible libraries, but turned up empty.

I'm hoping that by asking this on SO, I can get a definite answer on whether there is actually an existing library that I just hadn't had the luck to find, or if it doesn't really exist. Failing that, I'm thinking of writing my own library. If there is any XML library within PyS60 to make this task easier (I know the normal interpreter has libraries, but they don't appear to be portable to PyS60), that would be good.

The target device is a Nokia N78, Symbian 3rd Edition FP (Feature Pack) 2

Comment: I've found (pyexpat) http://pdis.hiit.fi/pdis/download/pyexpat/ for parsing XML, but it appears to be for 1st and 2nd edition devices only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to add native extensions to Python and there are lots of C/C++ libraries for XMPP that would port easily.

The previous pyexpat module is just bindings for native expat on Symbian, which is ported to S60 3rd Edition, so you should be able to get pyexpat working too.  Of course you need some ability with native development to do that...

You could try getting started and then ask for help in developer.symbian.org if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your help; We've decided not to create XML or XMPP libraries for PyS60, since we're doing rapid prototyping of proof-of-concepts, so we've opted for a JSON-to-XML gateway, and using JSON for the client.

Thanks again for your help!